# How to create an ImagePartition type-of-function that generates parts of different sizes

Tags: programming, image-processing

Background: I partition images to polygons ( squares ) and color them with VertexColors. I want to use a minimal number of polygons while still showing a clear resemblance of the original image. - Some images need more squares in the centre than along the edges ( i.e. portraits ). I want to create an ImagePartition type-of-function that uses a finer grid closer to the middle of a picture.

For example:

```
 1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5
 2-1 .           2-5
 3-1 .           3-5
 4-1 .           4-5
 5-1 5-2 5-3 5-4 5-5
 ( 5-by-5 )
```

The missing part

```
 2-2 2-3 2-4
 3-1 3-2 3-3
 4-1 4-2 4-3
```

is replaced with pieces from a 10-by-10 partitioning, i.e. 2-2 by:

```
 3-3 3-4
 4-3 4-4
```

and so on, until 4-3 is replaced with

```
  7-7 7-8
  8-7 8-8
```

from the 10-by-10 partitioning.

Finally 3-2 or ( 5-5, 5-6 / 6-5, 6-6 ) is replaced with the results from a 20-by-20 partitioning.

```
 9-9  9-10  9-11   9-12
 10-9 10-10 10-11 10-12
 11-9 11-10 11-11 11-12
 12-9 12-10 12-11 12-12.
```

In the case of 6-by-6 partitioning also three levels of partioning are used, in this case 6-by-6, 12-by-12, 24-by-24. And so on.

**Question: How to create an alternative ImagePartition function that creates a finer grid closer to the centre of the image. The output lists should be arranged in such a way that it is easy to re-assemble the image from the pieces.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate `ImagePartiton` on different sub-levels of previously applied `ImagePartiton`.

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]
p1 = ImagePartition[i, {100, 100}]; p1 // GraphicsGrid
```

[image]

Now pick the middle of your list and replace its elements with finer partiton:

```
p2 = p1; p2[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]] = Map[GraphicsGrid[ImagePartition[#, {20, 20}], 
Spacings -> 0, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> White, ImageSize -> 100] &, 
p1[[2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]], {2}]; Grid[p2, Spacings -> .3]
```

[image]

You can remove all grid wrappers of course - I kept them for visual comprehension. This is easy to pack into a function. You can continue partitioning in the same manner. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Wow! - Yes, image-wise this is about what I had in mind, but I need the parts for further processing in my program like ImagePartition. I'll study your answer first.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the Spacings Option you used. I am trying to get an equal spacing overall but that doesn't really work. Also setting spacings to 0 doesn't remove the horizontal spacing but it does so with the vertical spacing.

Comment: @ndroock1 `Spacings` option is for grid only. I thought you will omit `Grid`, because you need the list structure only. Nested grid structures are not really good things to have.

Comment: Yes, I will. I got it now, although somewhat struggling to make the code generic. But I'll get there. I always do.

Answer (score 9):

It seems quad-tree decomposition would suit your needs:
[image]
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QuadTreeImageDecomposition/

Comment: That looks great!  Would you please include executable code here, and a description of how to use it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Good answer, I agree, although not useful in my app. But you ask the OP to copy code from the Wolfram Demos site. Isn't the link sufficient?

Comment: @ndroock1 generally links alone are not considered good StackExchange answers, but I don't have time to find references for that statement right now.

Comment: I'll take your word for it @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll have to leave that to the interested readers. I just do not have the time right now to look into the potential licensing issues relevant to copying code from the Wolfram Demonstration website.

Comment: Matthias, I'm confused.  Isn't this your own code?  It says "Contributed by: Matthias Odisio" on the Demonstration page.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But of course I am! I forgot! Will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: LOL -- Forgetting more than the rest of us will ever know again? :o)